# OperationalError while connecting django and mysql other

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have problems when I try to connect the mysql database with my application in django.
'default': (1045, "Access denied for user 'PEPE'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
that user does not exist in the database and my settings.py file does not define it either

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "db_python",
        "DATABASE_USER": "root",
        "DATABASE_PASSWORD": "abc",
        "DATABASE_HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "DATABASE_PORT": "3306",
    }
}
```

I don't understand why django uses a different user when trying to establish the connection

inside the python shell I print the value of the settings_dict['DATABASE_USER'] variable and it shows the correct user 'root' but it doesn't use it to establish the connection

Answer (score 0):

It's not `DATABASE_USER`, etc., it's `USER`:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "db_python",
        "USER": "root",
        "PASSWORD": "abc",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "3306",
    }
}
```